# Issue Tracking System complying by a hierarchy

Tags: jira, bug-tracking, bugzilla, asana, issue-tracking

My company needs an Issue Tracking System. There are a lot of tools available on the internet and I have tried some (JIRA, Asana, Bugzilla to name a few). Most of them are great in the job they do. But we have a specific requirement that none seem to cater to. We need to implement a hierarchy in which certain users would have access to only certain parts of the system. Could you please suggest me a tool that could do what we want. May be the tools I tried do enable us to implement this hierarchical structure and couldn't figure out how to do it. In that case could you guide me as to how this could be done using the tools I have tried. It would be highly preferable not to develop the system ourselves owing to the time that would be consumed.

Thank you!

The hierarchy would be as follows:
[image: We need to implement a hierarchy of this kind in which the the resources would have issues to be resolved.]

P.S. - We are not an IT-based company. Hence, 'Site' does not refer to 'website'. Site is a geographic area which comprises of smaller units called locations where facilities are located. These facilities have certain resources that at times break down, a situation which needs to be efficiently tracked and be dealt with. Employees on-site would report issues which would be assigned to maintenance teams who would take care of the issue. The progress of the process of resolving the issue should also be tracked.

Comment: A warm welcome on SO :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could accomplish your goal using Bugzilla.  Although Bugzilla doesn't have hierarchical security groups per se, you could create groups with obviously hierarchical names, one for each node in your graph, e.g. site1, site1-location1, site1-location2, site1-location1-resource1, etc.  You could then assign each employee every group in the chain from the lowest to highest, e.g. (following your graph again), a user might have the groups site2, site2-location1, site2-location1-resource3.  Then you can assign each bug a group according to how many people should be able to access it; e.g. site2 if's a site-wide issue, or site2-location1 if it's a location-wide issue, and so on.

It's a bit tedious but you could write some scripts to automatically give those security groups to each employee based on their most specific permission level.

Comment: I tried Bugzilla and did not get much success initially. I will keep your suggestion in mind and will give it a try once again. What I need as a short term goal is that I need to generate excel sheet reports (for some time) for our clients. Would Bugzilla still remain a choice? @mcote

Comment: Yes, it's obviously a lot of work, but thanks anyway for another Bugzilla insight.

Comment: @MayankChoudhary You can export CSVs of any list of bugs in Bugzilla, which you could then import into Excel.